# Blender: Merge multiple actions

Tags: animation, blender

I have a model with several actions for different objects, see: [NLA editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RSc4P.png) 
My goal is now to create one single action for all these actions, similarly to: [other multi action solution](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/80550/is-it-possible-to-use-one-action-for-multiple-objects), but without using bones.
How can I achieve that? 
Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I doubt what you want to do will work. One action effects one object. You can use the same action on multiple objects, with each moving the same, the NLA editor allows you to adjust the timing of the actions so they don't have to be in sync.

To merge your animation into one action, you will need to merge your objects into one. If you have animated the object positions then the combined object will move as one solid object.

This is where an armature can be used to move a part of the object separate from the rest of it. Another option is using shape keys to move part of the object, but that only gives linear movement between two positions, complex animations will require a lot of different shapekeys be made for every frame. Either option will require re-creating the animation you have done.

While it is possible to [animate each vertex](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/78269/935), it's not really an easy task.

If you really needed to merge multiple animations together, I would use a python script to use your existing animation to create a replacement. I would use the script to make an armature for the combined mesh, but you could create shapekeys or vertex animations.